# Two sided (bidirectional) list in Java

Tags: java, list, data-structures, dictionary, bidirectional

Is there something like a two sided list in Java? Maybe a third party implementation?

Here a little example to demonstrate what I have in mind.

Original state:

```
A: 0-1-2-3
   | | | |
B: 0-1-2-3
```

After removal of element 1 in B:

```
    Null
     |
A: 0-1-2-3
   |  / /
B: 0-1-2
```

The data structure must be accessible from both sides. So it's more a mix of a bidirectional map and a list.

Things I thought about:
a) Using two lists that store Integer objects. The downside is that those must always be kept in sync.
b) Using a BidiMap from Apache Commons. The downside hereby is that it is unsorted and doesn't behave like a list when elements are removed (updating the other indidces).

Comment: If you gave a more precise/detailed definition of the expected behavior, you might get more answers.

Comment: Just to be precise, do you want a bidirectional map which nulls the other side and completely removes the entry from the other side?

Comment: It's more like two lists that are connected to each other. The value of one list is the index of the other. If one index of list B is removed then the appropriate index of list A (which was also the element of list B) is set to null (or -1 or something like that).

Comment: Do you have an example of what a bidirectional list can be used for?

Comment: I want to use it for some text processing. I have a string (let's name it master) and a copy of that string (let's name it slave). Now the slave is modified (inserts and deletions). I always want to know of each character in the slave the position in the master and vice versa.

Comment: That sounds a bit like what wikipedia's compare revisions or versioning. I'm unsure how that is done. Anyway, how about making a new container using two ArrayLists and three HashMaps?

Comment: Interesting question, but your example is quite confusing. You said "after removal of element 1 in B", but the example shows that element 1 of **A** is removed. Also, what happened with element 3 of B in the given example? Is it just dropped off? Without any reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I used two lists that save the positions viewed from each site.
As I always only modify one of the lists, the other will be recalculated.
Below the full code (if someone is interested). It is embedded into a JFace document class, but the logic could also be implemented somewhere else.

```
public class AdaptedDocument extends AbstractDocument implements IDocumentListener {

private IDocument masterDocument;

private List<Integer> masterToSlaveMapping;
private List<Integer> slaveToMasterMapping;

private boolean setMaster = true;
private boolean replaceMaster = true;

public AdaptedDocument(IDocument masterDocument) {

    super();

    this.masterDocument = masterDocument;
    masterDocument.addDocumentListener(this);

    setTextStore(new CopyOnWriteTextStore(new GapTextStore()));
    setLineTracker(new DefaultLineTracker());
    getStore().set(masterDocument.get());
    getTracker().set(masterDocument.get());
    initializeMappings();
    completeInitialization();
}

private void initializeMappings() {

    masterToSlaveMapping = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    slaveToMasterMapping = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i=0; i<masterDocument.getLength(); i++) {
        masterToSlaveMapping.add(i);
        slaveToMasterMapping.add(i);
    }
}

@Override
public void replace(int pos, int length, String text) throws BadLocationException {
    if (replaceMaster) {
        masterDocument.replace(pos, length, text);
    }
    super.replace(pos, length, text);
}

@Override
public void replace(int pos, int length, String text, long modificationStamp) throws BadLocationException {
    if (replaceMaster) {
        masterDocument.replace(pos, length, text);
    }
    super.replace(pos, length, text, modificationStamp);
}

@Override
public void set(String text) {
    if (setMaster) {
        masterDocument.set(text);
    }
    super.set(text);
}

@Override
public void set(String text, long modificationStamp) {
    if (setMaster) {
        if (masterDocument instanceof AbstractDocument) {
            ((AbstractDocument) masterDocument).set(text, modificationStamp);
        }
        else {
            masterDocument.set(text);
        }
    }
    super.set(text, modificationStamp);
}

public IDocument getMasterDocument() {
    return this.masterDocument;
}

public void removeTextFromSlave(int offset, int length) throws BadLocationException {

    if (length == 0) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        replaceSlaveOnly(offset, length, "");

        for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
            slaveToMasterMapping.remove(offset);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new BadLocationException();
    }

    rebuildMasterToSlaveMapping();
}

public void addTextToSlaveOnly(int offset, String text) throws BadLocationException {

    try {       
        replaceSlaveOnly(offset, 0, text);

        for (int i=0; i<text.length(); i++) {
            slaveToMasterMapping.add(offset + i, -1);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new BadLocationException();
    }

    rebuildMasterToSlaveMapping();
}

public void removeMasterDocumentRange(int offset, int length) throws BadLocationException {

    if (length == 0) {
        return;
    }

    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(get());

    try {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
            int slaveOffset = masterToSlaveMapping.get(offset+i);
            if (slaveOffset != -1) {
                buffer.deleteCharAt(slaveOffset - counter);
                slaveToMasterMapping.remove(slaveOffset - counter);
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new BadLocationException();
    }

    setSlaveOnly(buffer.toString());

    rebuildMasterToSlaveMapping();
}

public void addMasterDocumentRange(int offset, int length) throws BadLocationException {

    if (length == 0) {
        return;
    }

    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(get());
    String masterString = masterDocument.get();

    try {       
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
            int slaveOffset = masterToSlaveMapping.get(offset+i);
            if (slaveOffset == -1) {
                int insertIndex = 0;
                for (int j=offset+i; j>=0; j--) {
                    if (masterToSlaveMapping.get(j) != -1) {
                        insertIndex = masterToSlaveMapping.get(j)+1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                buffer.insert(insertIndex + counter, masterString.charAt(offset + i));
                slaveToMasterMapping.add(insertIndex + counter, offset+i);
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new BadLocationException();
    }

    setSlaveOnly(buffer.toString());

    rebuildMasterToSlaveMapping();
}

public int toMasterOffset(int offset) throws BadLocationException {
    try {
        return slaveToMasterMapping.get(offset);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new BadLocationException();
    }
}

public int toSlaveOffset(int offset) throws BadLocationException {
    try {
        return masterToSlaveMapping.get(offset);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new BadLocationException();
    }
}

public IRegion toMasterRegion(int offset, int length) throws BadLocationException {

    try {
        if (length == 0) {
            throw new BadLocationException();
        }
        int[] master = new int[length];
        for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
            master[i] = slaveToMasterMapping.get(offset+i);
            if (i > 0) {
                if (master[i] != (master[i-1] + 1)) {
                    throw new BadLocationException();
                }
            }
        }
        return new Region(master[0], master.length);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new BadLocationException();
    }
}

public IRegion toSlaveRegion(int offset, int length) throws BadLocationException {

    try {
        if (length == 0) {
            throw new BadLocationException();
        }
        int[] slave = new int[length];
        for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
            slave[i] = masterToSlaveMapping.get(offset+i);
            if (i > 0) {
                if (slave[i] != (slave[i-1] + 1)) {
                    throw new BadLocationException();
                }
            }
        }
        return new Region(slave[0], slave.length);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new BadLocationException();
    }
}

@Override
public void documentAboutToBeChanged(DocumentEvent event) {
}

@Override
public void documentChanged(DocumentEvent event) {
    setSlaveOnly(masterDocument.get());
}

private void setSlaveOnly(String text) {
    setMaster = false;
    super.set(text);
    setMaster = true;
}

private void replaceSlaveOnly(int pos, int length, String text) throws BadLocationException {
    replaceMaster = false;
    super.replace(pos, length, text);
    replaceMaster = true;
}

private void rebuildMasterToSlaveMapping() {

    int length = masterDocument.getLength();

    masterToSlaveMapping.clear();

    for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
        masterToSlaveMapping.add(-1);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<slaveToMasterMapping.size(); i++) {
        int masterOffset = slaveToMasterMapping.get(i);
        if (masterOffset != -1) {
            masterToSlaveMapping.set(masterOffset, i);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Google](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) has a bi-directional map.

Comment: Thanks for the hint (I was only aware of the Apache Commons implementation). The downside with maps is that it doesn't behave like lists (what I need). If I remove one key/index then I have to adjust all the others by myself. It is also not possible to iterate it in an ordered way like a list :-(